# Application text size not scaling with system font size

Tags: android, fonts, scale-independent

I had to work on an existing Android application, where all the texts are mentioned in SP unit in layout XML files.

However, the text size of the application is not adjusted along with the system font. ie, if i change the system font size from `Settings -> Accessibility -> Font Size`, the application's font size does not change at all.

PFB an excerpt from my layout file, where the `TextView's` `textSize` is mentioned in SP.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/find_an_noffice"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I do not think the issue is related to the layout structure and hence i have used the same layout file in a sample application. This sample application is working as expected. ie, the app's font size is adjusted with the system font.

What can be the possibilities by which my original application was not behaving as the sample app?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, to be clear: this same layout is working in App A, but not App B? If so, what is different about the two apps? For example, are their themes different?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for the comment. Yes, the same layout is working in a AppA not in AppB. They both use the same theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. This is what confuses me as well.  Is there any other possibilities for the fonts being not scaling?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind.

Comment: @CommonsWare I got solution. Please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the root cause of the issue. My app was creating a new `Configuration` which was causing the issue.

The code that causes this issue:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(isSpanish() ? "es" : "en");
Locale.setDefault(locale);

Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

If I change the line `Configuration config = new Configuration();` to `Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();` the application font will scale according to the system font size changes.

Hope this may help someone.